# Complexity of algorithms and complexity of problems. What are the differences?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, computation-theory, space-complexity

I would like to know the difference between the **complexity of an algorithm** and the **complexity of a problem**, that is, which points differ from the two things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question! Most people make no distinction between the two, which is a big no-no.

Simply put, the **complexity of an algorithm** is the algorithm's running time. This could be represented many ways, big O, big Theta, or any of the assorted [Landau Notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_notation). There also other representations, but the most commonly used in big O notation, which can be applied to analyze the worst-case time complexity of an algorithm as a function of the input size.

The **complexity of a problem** is typically the lower bound of any algorithm that solves the problem ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory#Upper_and_lower_bounds_on_the_complexity_of_problems) is a decent resource here). For example we can prove comparison-based sorting has a lower bound of `n log n`. This means, any algorithm that sorts by comparing elements, no matter which algorithm, will take at least `n log n` time in the worst case. Using Landau notation we would say this problem takes `Omega(n log n)`.

In summary, problem complexity is a lower bound and algorithm typically establishes an upper bound. When you find an algorithm whose upper bound matches a problem's lower bound, you've found an asymptotically optimal algorithm!

Comment: It's not true that "big O notation" "represents the worst-case time complexity of an algorithm as the input size grows towards infinity"; rather, big-O notation represents an asymptotic upper bound on a function. One very common application of it is to worst-case time complexities of algorithms as functions of input size, but the same notation can be used for average-case time complexity, worst-case space complexity, etc., and the other Landau notations can likewise be used for any of these.

Comment: @ruakh, fair point. I've updated it as an application of big-O, rather than an exact meaning or such. Thank you for pointing that out.